# "Ambiguous type name 'index' in Array'" Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

[image]

This is my code:

```
func didMarkAsFavoriteContact(_ contact: Contact) {
    var outerIndex: Array.Index? = nil
}
```

Comment: Welcome Amaury. It's always better to copy/past your code so we can dupilcate your scenario

Comment: What do you actually want to do? The error is because there is no class property `Index` for `Array`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My apologies guys! I think I didn't properly explained myself in the first place. However, I was able to figure it out!! Thanks @TheTiger and Rob.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do but if you just want to initialize something that can serve as an index you can do something like this:

```
var outerIndex: Int? = nil
```

Comment: That's pretty what I was trying to do.. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AmauryC ok well you can accept the answer if it helped